# Parsing string of a cell to cell

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have the following string in MATLAB:

```
contents = '{'aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd'}'
```

I need to get the 1x4 cell-array inside it, like:

```
mycell = {'aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd'}
```

How would you do it? Is there a quicker way than parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the double quote inside the string and use `eval` (ugly solution but simple and working).

```
>> contents = '{''aa'' ''bb'' ''cc'' ''dd''}'

contents =

{'aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd'}

>> c = eval(contents)

c = 

    'aa'    'bb'    'cc'    'dd'

>> class(c)

ans =

cell

>> c{2}

ans =

bb
```

Comment: If you type Clement J's answer directly into matlab's command window (with double single-quotations), it works fine. Since I'm getting contents from excel using xlsread( ), I can type {'aa' 'bb' 'cc' 'dd'} straight into the spreadsheet and eval( ) evaluates it well. I don't understand this better-then-expected behaviour. Anyway, eval solves it (powerful function right!) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nifty way (if I've captured your initial question correctly)

```
>> contents = '{aa bb cc dd}';
>> result = regexp(contents,'\w+','match')
result = 
    'aa'    'bb'    'cc'    'dd'
```

"result" is a 1x4 cell.

Comment: A better pattern would be '\w*' (I assume the 2 letter word are just for the example).

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas. This is correct either, but since I'm also reading cells of cells, eval( ) does the work more properly.